# Create string and wide string literals from a single definition

Tags: c++, windows, macros, string-literals, widechar

Sometimes there is need to create string literals with the same value for both `char *` and `wchar_t *` types (e.g. when developing in Windows). A simply way is to write the definition twice:

```
const char *my_string = "Hello World";
const wchar_t *my_wide_string = L"Hello World";
```

The problem is that if we need to change the string, instead of just changing one place, both lines need to be updated, often lead to typos and bugs. Ideally the literal should only appear once and both variables are populated from it.

We could define the `char` variable and convert it to the `wchar_t` version at runtime. However, it is better to avoid the runtime cost since the literal is already available at compile time.

I thought to use the token-pasting operator, but can't make it work because it only accepts another string literal:

```
#define my_string "Hello World"
#define make_wide(str) L##str
#define my_wide_string make_wide(my_string)  // expand to Lmy_string instead of L"Hello World"
```

I'm not sure if one can use `constexpr` to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need another macro so the argument of the macro is expanded before pasting:

```
#include <wchar.h>

#define my_string "Hello World"

#define WidenHelper(x)  L##x
#define Widen(x)        WidenHelper(x)

const char *plain   = my_string;
const wchar_t *wide = Widen(my_string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're on Windows you can use `_STR2WSTR` in crtdefs.h which gets included when you `#include <windows.h>`. There are also `__FILEW__` and `__FUNCTIONW__` made from the normal string variant as examples

```
/* error reporting helpers */
#define __STR2WSTR(str)    L##str
#define _STR2WSTR(str)     __STR2WSTR(str)

#define __FILEW__          _STR2WSTR(__FILE__)
#define __FUNCTIONW__      _STR2WSTR(__FUNCTION__)
```

**Update:**

Later CRT versions have change that to `_CRT_WIDE`

```
#define _CRT_WIDE_(s) L ## s
#define _CRT_WIDE(s) _CRT_WIDE_(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely that you want both versions in a proper design. Anyway, the two types (`char` and `wchar_t`) are not compatible (8/16 bits) so you can't do it at the compile level.

Design a class that uses wchar_t and converts to char only when necessary. You use [WideCharToMultiByte](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-widechartomultibyte) for this.

Design your entire application to only use wide characters and only use UTF-8 forms when serializing.

Comment: Proper design: one situation is that my application is multi-byte, but some APIs/libraries only accept `wchar_t*` (fortunately only for these literals). Not compatible: I understand they are completely different representations, but I'm hoping the compiler could do the computation for me, instead of requiring me to write the same value twice.

Comment: It can't. Redesign your application to use wide forms (and quit the char version completely), or, if you can't do that, create a convertor class that would switch on request.

Comment: Considering that `char` is actually preferred for UTF-8 (https://utf8everywhere.org/), and even Windows is adding UTF-8 support (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_in_Microsoft_Windows#UTF-8), I was trying to stay with `char`.

Comment: Most systems use wide strings. (Windows, Java, Android, iOS). UTF-8 is generally used in nix and in data interchanging. It's slower and It makes iteration through a string impossible. In Windows applications, always use wide strings. UTF-8 is *not at all* everywhere.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis UTF8 is nowadays the prefered way to handle unicode. the 16bit chars have the same problems because there are more than 2^16 codepoints, so some characters also need more than one byte.